# How do I filter a column of character strings based on their first and 3rd characters?

Tags: r, filter, icd

I've got a dataset of ICD codes, 5 digit codes which describe the diagnosis of a hospital patients, which looks like this (but with 16000 patients):

```
df <- c('S48.10', 'H38.13', 'R40.12')
```

I need to filter them based on the first character being an S and the third character being an 8 to filter out amputation patients. Any advice on how to do this?

Comment: `ICD[substring(ICD, 1, 1) == "S" & substring(ICD, 3, 3) == "8"]`

Answer (score 0):

Here is an option with `grepl` on the ICD column.  The pattern used is 'S' followed by any character (`.`) followed by 8 from the start (`^`) of the string to filter the rows of the datasest

```
subset(df1, grepl('^S.8', ICD))
```